# Is there any best practice for packaging MVP layers?

Tags: java, android, mvp

I have done some Android applications using MVP methodology,

But I am not so sure if it is better to place different layers objects of the same feature in a same package? or package all layers items of different features in the same package with layer name on it?

(Which I mean something like this)

[image: Packages Screenshot]

Currently, I am following the second rule, but is this the best practice?

**Edit**: This is my project's whole packages! :)

[image: Packages bigger screenshot]

Comment: in my experience basically it depends upon the module like to restrict the access over default fields and function , the image shows a good practice  and brings clarity about project though if you have some module which works as a separate dependency the would be a better approach to  pack in different package or sub-package

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the point is this is whole packages of the project not a single module! maybe I have to extend the picture. do you think it is okay, too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to throw my thoughts into the mix.  I have worked on projects with each of these approaches. My preference now is to package by feature.  There are two main reasons I prefer this approach:

**Ease of Induction**

Increased visibility of project structure for developers new to the codebase. When classes which relate to a single feature are grouped together it is much easier for a new team member to quickly see how everything fits together.

**Restricting Class access**

This is probably more important.  When you package by type (all Presenters together, etc) you have to give many methods in these classes `public` access.  This can lead to these functions being used inappropriately from various areas of the codebase.

If you package by feature then these classes are all in the same package and as such you can give the methods package level access.  This ensures that methods don't leak.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really accept the **Restricting Class access** part. It was very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Create a feature-specific package which contains a `Contract` `interface` containing the `View` and `Presenter` interfaces. The feature package also contains implementations of the `View` and `Presenter` interfaces (i.e. the `Activity` and `Presenter` classes).


I have made a [sample project here](https://github.com/dakshj/TMDb_Sample/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/daksh/tmdbsample/movielist); you may refer it for more info on MVP.

Comment: Thanks for the sample, I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You should create separate package for base MVP classes and package for each MVP - entity. Say, 'mvp_base' for basic stuff and 'some_screen' package, inside which you'll be having your Activity, Fragments, etc. Concrete mvp implementation for 'some screen' put in 'mvp' package inside 'some_screen' package. 
It is also a good idea to store all your models and presenter inside Service and bind to it upon UI creation.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this packaging model in main package:

[image]

- Common classes take place in main.
- Every package is a feature of app or a layer of app.
- Data: Data Layer. Contains classes which use for data. For example domain classes, repository classes, data source classes etc.
- If you design **Mvp - Clean architecture** and do your business in `Interactor` classes. (or `Use-Case` classes) you can create a `domain` package in related feature and put them this location.
- Util contains util classes.
- View and presenters get defined in a class called `Contract`.

Here is an example of `Contract` class:

```
interface SupportContract {
    interface View extends BaseView {
        void showTenthChar(char c);

        void showEveryTenthChar(@NonNull char[] chars);

        void showEveryWordWithCount(@NonNull HashMap<String, Integer> data);
    }

    interface Presenter extends BasePresenter<View> {
        void onSupportDataRequested();
    }
}
```

According to me the main benefit of this model is someone when see the package model can easily understand the layers, features and requirements of app.